# Is there a canonical programmatic way to query for the set of cores belonging to a NUMA node?

Tags: linux, multicore, numa

One can obtain the set of cores belonging to each NUMA node using the following shell command.

```
$ lscpu | grep NUMA
NUMA node(s):          2
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-7,16-23
NUMA node1 CPU(s):     8-15,24-31
```

While it is not difficult to parse this output to determine the set of cores belonging to each NUMA node, it is fragile to depend on the formatted output of a shell command to collect such information.

**Is there a canonical API in Linux to determine which set of cores belong to which NUMA node?**

For example, a system call or a set of files under `/proc` or `/sys`.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the source code of `lscpu` and the [kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/stable/sysfs-devices-node), it looks like the relevant information is available at the following two special paths for each NUMA node.

```
/sys/devices/system/node/nodeX/cpulist
/sys/devices/system/node/nodeX/cpumap
```

Moreover, one can get the names of the NUMA nodes from the following path.

```
/sys/devices/system/node/possible
```